# how to get the product of two columns in a table?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jbutton

I am developing a GUI Desktop application using Netbeans. I have made a veriable for the total which does not show the result. Please check out the coding weather if there are some changes to do or if is it wrong. When I execute it, in column 3 it shows error and there is no result

```
private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    try {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
    try {
        con= DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:food");
        stmt= con.createStatement();

        String st= JcbSub.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String qt= quantity.getText().toString();
        String query;

        Double u_p= (Double) jTable3.getValueAt(row, 1);
        Integer qut= (Integer) jTable3.getValueAt(row, 2);
        Double tot= u_p * qut; //product of column 1 & column 2


        query="select i_price from food where i_name='"+JcbSub.getSelectedItem()+"'";
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){
        jTable3.setValueAt(st, row, 0);
        jTable3.setValueAt(rs.getString("i_price"), row, 1); 
        jTable3.setValueAt(qt, row, 2);
        jTable3.setValueAt(tot, row, 3);  //result column

        row ++;
        }

       } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing it in the query e.g. Select X,Y,Z, X * Y as Total From Table ???

Comment: actually the values in column 1 is selected from the database table and and column 2 values are entered manually using jTextField and transferred to column 2

Comment: If it were me I'd be defining a class to hold the row, with a total function. Then build a colection of them filling them in from whereever, and then bind that to the grid.

Comment: Or just pass the manually input values to the query Select iprice,@qty,@qty * iPrice rom SomeTable Where SomeKey = @KeyValue

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more i am not getting your concept.

Answer (score 2):

> actually the values in column 1 is selected from the database table and and column 2 values are entered manually using jTextField and transferred to column 2

Extend your TableModel and override the setValueAt() method.

Whenever the value in column 1 or 2 changes (and both contain non-null values) you should calculate the product and update column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do java, but use a parameterised query and for instance do something like

```
query="select name, i_price, @qty,@total, @qty*@total from food where i_name=@name"
```

add the parameters to the query, set their values to  qt, tot and st, and Bob is your mothers sister's brother, and you don't have a potential sql injection attack as well...

[OWASP guidance Java parameterised queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)